PDFBox - Image Processing
I am working on code that will check each of the images in a PDF and do some image processing.
As a proof of concept, to check that my image processing worked, I wrote a simple page parser that check for a PDImageXObject and processed that, replacing the image with a processed one. That worked so I am looking to extend the code because, as we all know, real PDFs can have PDFormXObjects that reference PDFormXObjects that reference PDImageXObjects etc.
Researching this, I looked at the examples PrintImageLocations.java as a starter. That appeared to be a good path to go down until I came across this where @mkl implied that it would not "find" all the images in a PDF, specifically those in a PDFormXObject.
Can anyone enlighten me, provide guidance or point me at some sample code?
Thanks in advance.
Tried parsing the PDF Page. Researched other techniques i.e. PrintImageLocations.java
     protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException
        {
            // Check for "Do" then examine the previous token for the PDXImageObject and then process the image content
            String operation = operator.getName();
            if (OperatorName.DRAW_OBJECT.equals(operation))   
            {
                COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get( 0 );    
                PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject( objectName ); 
                if( xobject instanceof PDImageXObject)
                {                   
                    PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject)xobject;
                    BufferedImage bi = ((PDImageXObject)xobject).getImage();

                    BufferedImage newBufferedImage = renderBufferedImage (bi);
                    
          }
        }

The example referenced earlier 'put' the modified PDImageXObject back into the page level resources and while that works for 'simple' cases, it isn't the right way to handle the case for PDFormXObjects(where it should be placed in the resources of the associated PDFormXObject).
Is there a way to determine the parent of the PDImageXObject to be able to replace it at that level or do I need to create some sort of structure (a Map?) to hold the name of the original PDImageXObject and processed image and replace everything once the processOperator is complete?

Do you have a sample that doesn't work?  Or are you anticipating trouble that might not actually exist?

As you refer to a comment of mine: I don't know anymore why I thought that inline images in form Objects are not found by the code. But they at least are not replaced as the replacer does not go into then.

Tim, I anticipate trouble trying to replace the modified PDImageXObject when it is a child of a PDFormXObject as I can't see a way for a child to know who the parent is. With "simple" files that only have a PDImageXObject as part of the Page Resources, I could simply "put" the new one into the resources.
@mkl yes the images are all "enumerated" and can be processed but I am having difficulty understanding how to approach replacing the old PDImageXObject with the new one.

First of all, you want to "check each of the images in a PDF and do some image processing"; what kind of checks are involved, how do you want to process? In particular, do you need to know where and how the image in question is displayed? Or do you only need the image itself?
In the former case please be aware that an image resource can be used in multiple locations in different ways on a page, so be prepared to additionally rename the image resources you change.
In the latter case you don't need to parse the content streams except for inline image processing...

Thanks for your feedback, much appreciated. I want to down sample the image and replace the one in the original PDF with the new one.

In that case iterate over the pages and retrieve the page resources. First inspect all XObjects. If they are image XObjects, manipulate them. Then inspect all resources that themselves can have resources, in particular patterns and form XObjects and recursively process their resources. And beware, the same image resource may be in multiple resource collections, so when manipulating an image better first check whether you already have manipulated it.

I came to a similar conclusion and now have a working processor. That said I think I will need to update the code, to make sure images are processed more than once. Thanks for taking the time to provide some guidance, much appreciated.
